# Obtener modo de precisión de la ubicación en la configuración de Android

Tags: java, android, android-settings

Dentro de configuración del sistema en el apartado `ubicación` el usuario puede establecer la precisión de la obtención de la localización GPS, Red, etc...

Lo modos que me salen:

- **Gran precisión:**
  Usar GPS, WI-FI, Bluetooth y redes móviles para determina la ubicación:
- **Ahorro de batería:**
  Usar WI-FI, Bluetooth y redes móviles para determinar la ubicación.
- **Solo dispositivo:**
  Usar GPS para determinar su ubicación.

¿Es posible obtener qué modo tiene establecido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25745124/3683321) que puede servirte en SO en inglés, en la que explica como obtener el modo de precisión actual. Es posible obtener esta característica a partir del **API 19 (Kitkat)**, mediante el siguiente código:

```
public int getLocationMode(Context context)
{
      return Settings.Secure.getInt(activityUnderTest.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
}
```

Estos son los posibles valores que puede devolver (ver [documentación](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_MODE) de **LOCATION_MODE**):

**0 = LOCATION_MODE_OFF

1 = LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY

2 = LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING

3 = LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY**